# Convert ViewModel to concrete entity type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a ViewModel similar to below structure

```
class ManagerViewModel
{
    string Name;
    long salary;
    string workType;
    //8 more such properties
    List<EmployeeViewModel> Dependents;
}
class EmployeeViewModel
{
    string Name;
    long salary;
    string workType;
    //8 more such properties
    List<EmployeeViewModel> Dependents;
}
```

I need to convert Manager view Model into Entity. But the Entity could be concreteType like GardenManager or ShopManager (but having same properties as ManagerViewModel).

ShopManager can have a child dependent as a GardenManager and Gardenmanager can have child dependent as some other concreteType.

If the workType in the ViewModel is "Shop", then the ViewModel should be converted to a ShopManager and likewise for child dependents as well.

Sample Entities mentioned below.

```
class Manager
{
    string Name;
    string Salary;
    List<Employee> reportees;
    void abstract SayHi();
}
class ShopManager() : Manager
{
    public override void SayHi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey I am a ShopManager");
    }
}
class GardenManager() : Manager
{
    public override void SayHi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey I am a GardenManager");
    }
}
```

Is there a good way to transform such DTO to Entity?

Comment: You could use http://automapper.org/ for that.

Comment: @Kenneth I can not use automapper in this case, because I have to do the viewModel to entity conversion based on the viewModel property(updated the question) and also I have 20+ concrete entity classes

Comment: Well, you need to tell it what to map to, there's nothing that can do that automatically for you. You can use the `workType` in a switch-statement and then call the correct overload of AutoMapper. That way at least you can use AutoMapper to benefit from the convention based mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using AutoMapper as suggested, you could use implicit operator on your POCO classes or use ExtensionMethods to do your conversions:

**TestProgram:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagerViewModel viewModel = new ManagerViewModel
        {
            workType = "Garden"
        };

        // By implicit conversion
        Manager manager1 = viewModel;
        manager1.SayHi();

        // By extension method
        ShopManager manager2 = viewModel.ToEntity<ShopManager>();
        manager2.SayHi();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Hey I am a GardenManager
>
> Hey I am a ShopManager

**Implicit Operator sample:**

```
public class ManagerViewModel
{
    public string Name;
    public long salary;
    public string workType;
    public List<EmployeeViewModel> Dependents;

    //  User-defined conversion from ManagerViewModel to ShopManager or GardenManager
    public static implicit operator Manager(ManagerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        switch (viewModel.workType)
        {
            case "Shop":
                // TODO: Do your conversion, Build ShopManager based on ManagerViewModel
                return new ShopManager();
            case "Garden":
                // TODO: Do your conversion, Build GardenManager based on ManagerViewModel
                return new GardenManager();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

[Implicit (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)

**ExtensionMethod sample:**

```
internal static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static TSpecificManager ToEntity<TSpecificManager>(this ManagerViewModel managerViewModel)
        where TSpecificManager : new()
    {
        // Do your conversion based on ManagerViewModel
        return new TSpecificManager();
    }
}
```

[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb383977.aspx)

Hope it helps